# Windows PC always has many updates to complete when I come back after a few days, CPU locked up

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, cpu-usage, anti-malware

I have an HP laptop a few years old that I often leave closed (I think in sleep mode) for a few days at a time. When I come back, for the next twenty minutes or so, Windows starts running various tasks that use 100% CPU. In the task manager I can see it's often System or Antimalware Service, etc. using all that CPU and freezing the computer.

I am guessing it is finishing whatever it needs to do for the latest updates to Windows (currently have Windows 10), or malware scans.

Is there any way I can get it to do these various tasks regardless of whether my computer is in sleep mode, so I don't have to wait for all of them to be done in succession whenever it has been a few days since last using the PC?

Windows Update certainly seems to be able to run on its own, because I sometimes open it up to find that it has apparently rebooted because my apps are closed.

I have not changed the Windows Security settings from the defaults since my last computer wipe / Windows reinstall.

Comment: Turn it ON and leave it for 24 hours for one day a week to fix this. It does not fully run while sleeping so forget that.

Comment: Do you know of a way to schedule the computer to wake up for half an hour maybe every day at 4am? Maybe with a utility that can be installed.

Comment: You can try an Admin Task schedule to do that. I think that can wake it up.

Comment: Look in Admin Task Scheduler in the conditions section. You can turn the computer ON to do what you want.